# When microtype is loaded, tabular's content displayed identically in ordinary tabular but not in tabularray's tabular

Tags: tables, microtype, tabularray

In the following MCE, “Foo : Bar” is displayed (almost) the same way both inside an ordinary `tabular` tabular and inside a `tblr` tabular:

```latex
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
% \usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\begin{tabular}{r@{ }l}
  Foo : & Bar
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {r@{ }l},
  }
  Foo : & Bar
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If `% \usepackage{microtype}` is uncommented, “Foo : Bar” isn't changed in the ordinary `tabular` tabular but is changed inside the `tblr` tabular:

[image]

Do you understand what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier to see with a paragraph break

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
% \usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\begin{tabular}{r@{ }l}
Foo 

Foo2 : & Bar
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {r@{ }l},
  }
Foo

Foo2 : & Bar
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

`tabularray` is setting the entries as paragraphs (like `varwidth`) so triggers microtype.

---

You can locally disable protrusion so the `:` at the end of the cell is not adjusted

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
 \usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\begin{tabular}{r@{ }l}
Foo : & Bar
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {r@{ }l},
  }
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}%
Foo : & Bar
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Done inline here but you could set it up as part of the `tblr` column spec.

Comment: Sorry, I should have ask: how to have the same horizontal space before “Bar” when `microtype` is loaded?

Comment: you could disable protrusion for the tblr with `\microtypecontext{protrusion=false}`

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I added an example